# Secure page access using resolve (Firebase, AngularJS and UI-ROUTER)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, resolve

I need some help with my Single-Page-Application app I'm building with AngularJS and AngularFire Firebase.

Basically, I've tried following these instructions as best I can to simply prevent access to a secure page that requires authentication, if not redirect the user to the [login page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers).

The app seems to work if I change `'currentAuth'` to `'Auth'` in the 'loginCtrl', albeit with the following error:

1. I **could** still access the `'securePage'` using this format typed in the address bar:

> https://.firebaseio.com/#/securePage.

The page is blank but there are errors noticeable in the console and by viewing the page source.

I basically need to know if my code is actually correct by following the instructions for the use of the UI-ROUTER using the 'resolve' method. I just simply want to redirect the user to the login view no matter what method they could use to attempt to view the 'securePage'???

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content=
    "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    name="viewport">
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <base href="/">
    <title>
        App
    </title>
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href=
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script defer="defer" src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" src=
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" src=
    "https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" src=
    "https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" src=
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script defer="defer" src="app.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div data-ui-view=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ui.router']);

app.factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth',
    function($firebaseAuth) {
        var ref = new Firebase(
            'https://<MYURL>.firebaseio.com/');
        return $firebaseAuth(ref);
    }
]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state',
    function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', '$stateChangeStart',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,
                fromParams, error) {
                if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
                    $state.go('/home');
                }
                event.preventDefault();
                window.history.forward();
            });
    }
]);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .state('securePage', {
            url: '/securePage',
            templateUrl: 'secure-page.html',
            resolve: {
                'currentAuth': ['Auth',
                    function(Auth) {
                        return Auth.$requireAuth();
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    }
]);

app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'currentAuth', '$state',
    function($scope, currentAuth, $state) {

        $scope.signin = function() {
            currentAuth.$authWithPassword({
              email: $scope.email,
              password: $scope.password
            }).then(function(authData) {
              console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
            }).catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

**login.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof app === 'undefined') {
            document.location.href = "index.html";
        }
    </script>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span>
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input data-ng-model="email" type="email" id="email" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
            </span>
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input data-ng-model="password" type="text" id="password" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button data-ng-click="signin()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn- 
    block" id="signInButton" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

**secure-page.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof app === 'undefined') {
            document.location.href = "index.html";
        }
    </script>

    <div>
        <h1>Secure Page</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ignore the Firebase URL error above https://.firebaseio.com/#/securePage. I simply mean with the correct part before the '.'  ;)

Comment: Your `loginCtrl` should be using `Auth`, not `currentAuth` as a dependency. `currentAuth` is only available to the `securePage` state (and its children). Otherwise, the resolve looks correct. Are you sure you're not authenticated when testing accessing /securePage?

Comment: Hi Anid, thanks for the response! I've managed to fix it now by changing it back to 'Auth' as you are have confirmed my initial understanding on that issue. I do think the Firebase page is actually incorrect then as they've included 'currentAuth' as a dependency in the two controllers...

Comment: Also, you do have to be authenticated to be able to access the 'securePage' as stated, otherwise the state won't load. I have finally realised that removing the '$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);' line (app.js) and '<base href="/">' (index.html) and sticking to '/#/' the old 'ugly urls' method is the most cross-compatible method to prevent issues.